# Cloudformation helper script (bash) is not running as expected

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, cloud-init

I am trying to setup an Autoscaling group with rolling updates which will kick-in in case of any changes to ec2 launch configurations. I am using a sample [template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/AutoScaling/AutoScalingRollingUpdates.yaml) from aws labs. This works fine for Amazon linux AMI. I have changed the template to work for Ubuntu. Now everything runs fine I can see from /var/log/cfn-init.log that my script was initiated properly, below is the script I am using to check health of my ec2 instance:

```
verify_instance_health:
          commands:
            ELBHealthCheck:
              command: !Sub
                'until [[ $state == *InService* ]]; do state=$(aws --region ${AWS::Region} elb describe-instance-health
                 --load-balancer-name ${ElasticLoadBalancer}
                 --instances $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
                 --query InstanceStates[0].State);echo $(date): [$state] >> /tmp/health.log;sleep 10;done'
```

If I run the script directly from terminal it runs fine and works as expected, but when this runs via cloudformation show how the condition:

> until [[ $state = *InService* ]]

Is never evaluated to be true which makes it keep on running. I have verified from /tmp/health.log that output is "InService". Anyone has faced this issue? What can cause this script to behave differently.

Comment: Do you know that it's running with bash and not sh?

Comment: How can I check that? I have also tried single '=' just in case it is running using sh. Can you give me some direction how can I debug this?

Comment: You can use `exec 2>> /tmp/mylog; set -x; yourcommand` to see debug output for your job

Comment: I have this ">> /tmp/health.log" in my script. The log file shows that the condition shuld meet but for some reason the script runs indefinitely. Not sure why 'until' is not matching the condition. Can you suggest any other way to achieve this? Thanks for your response.

Comment: See the debug output for the job.